# Site usage report in Sharepoint online for more than 7 days

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage

Customer asked for usage report for SharePoint online site collection. What i see in Site Usage report is data is provided for last 7 days. but user would like to go for last one month. Would like to know if there is any configuration settings available where i can change the date or do I need to build a custom application.

I followed this microsoft article but it only explains the feature https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-usage-data-for-your-SharePoint-Online-site-2fa8ddc2-c4b3-4268-8d26-a772dc55779e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be able to get full month by going to:

site collection level:

/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSiteCollection

or site level:

/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSite

it only gives you the old format of how many and not who in an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Office-365-Auditing-Tool-01747cd4
The above tool will have the option to export/browse the site usage metrics for a longer period.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below to use it.

1. Settting up the SharePoint Online Management Shell Windows PowerShell environment by following https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.
2. Download the GetSPOTenantStroageReport.ps1 to your desktop.
3. Start the SharePoint Online PowerShell as administrator and run cd c:\users\username\desktop.
4. Run the command “Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted” and input y for confirmation for allowing the computer run script
5. Run the following command:
   .\GetSPOTenantStroageReport.ps1 -searchCenter https://.sharepoint.com/search -admin  -password  -adminSiteUrl https://-admin.sharepoint.com
   Note: Replace  with your own tenant domain and replace  and  with the admin credentials.
6. After the script is completed, a SPOTenantStroageReport.csv file will appear on your desktop. All the site collections’ usage will be listed.

For more information, please refer the following article.

[View reports on site usage](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-search-usage-reports-2CD8F257-C29B-423D-8265-D44E6214D095)

[SharePoint Online – Usage Reporting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/05/28/sharepoint-online-usage-reporting/)

Comment: I am looking for a particular site collection and not for all site collection in my tenant. Also Its for end user who can access it anytime he wish . He wont be running powershell command for that.  It is a feature which we would like to provide to user. right now the feature gives site data for 7 days